# Post facebook open graph objects without url

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

We have a mobile app. When a user achieves something he earns a badge. The badge is posted into facebook timeline.

It has just few properties: title, description and image.

Since we develop mobile-app, we don't have a site except of API-server.

Our problem is that all posted badges have clickable title which references to our API url, or to the url of empty page with og-metatags of that object.

Is there a way to suppress link on the object title? If we omit "og:url" from the object description then it's generated automatically.

Comment: The base principle behind Open Graph is that it is based on URLs that users can visit and get (more) information about an object. If you are not providing that, I’d say maybe you shouldn’t be using Open Graph in the first place …

Comment: I thought that Open Graph gives ability to share custom objects, not just urls or text. That's really strange requirement for me that I need some web-site for creating objects. We solved that by adding js that redirects user to another site of our partner.